# C# Replacing each words with random generated string

Tags: c#, random, replace

Hello people of StackOverFlow, I have a problem with the buggy code below that I wrote. My question is how can I replace each of those words below with random generated string.

My problem is that the code  below, right now it is replacing all of the words randomly but all of them is same and what I want is replacing each of them with randomly generated string not all of them same..

I have used these string multiple times in resources so.

My words that I have in resource is : "basenet", "R02", "R01", "R03", "R0",     "vistubularcut", "naturalipad", "braskausa", "moonsteelir", "dubilomo"

my code :

```c#
public string RandomGen1(int a1, Random random) {
  StringBuilder result1 = new StringBuilder(a1);
  string characters = textBox1.Text;
  for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++) {
    result1.Append(characters[random.Next(characters.Length)]);
  }
  return result1.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    string[] gen1 = new string[1];
    for (int a = 0; a < gen1.Length; a++) {
      gen1[a] = RandomGen1(1, rnd);
      string source = (String.Join(Environment.NewLine, gen1));
      string executionerv2 = Properties.Resources.String1;

      string[] replace1 = {
        "basenet",
        "R02",
        "R01",
        "R03",
        "R0",
        "vistubularcut",
        "naturalipad",
        "braskausa",
        "moonsteelir",
        "dubilomo"
      };

      foreach (string curr in replace1) {
        executionerv2 = executionerv2.Replace(curr, source);
      }
    }
```

Comment: A list of things you want isn't a question.  **What's your question**? This isn't a service for debugging your buggy code; if you have a clear, specific question that has an answer, ask that question. If you want advice on learning how to debug your buggy code, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Ashlou `foreach` is the proper keyword for that type of loop in C#. Your edit changed it to `for each` which is incorrect. Please take care when editing others' code, especially in questions.

Comment: @EricLippert Well, my question is how can I replace each of  those words with random generated string.

Comment: You want the string that is being used as the replacement to be random or you want to select one of the strings in your array at random as the replacement string?

Comment: @BMinster Basically I want to replace all of them and I want  all of them to be random.

Comment: The way you solve that problem is you break it down into two smaller problems:  (1) generate a random string, and (2) replace a word.  Do you know how to do those two things? If not, which one is the the one you need help with?  Again, **ask a specific question**.  Break your problem down into the smallest part you don't understand, because *we don't know what you don't know*.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks.  I already put the code that is generating random string and I'm sorry I forget to mention that.
I'm JUST asking how can I replace each of  the **"words"** with the random generated string that I have wrote there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Random` to generate random numbers, convert them to `char` and append to a `string`.

```
private string RandomString(int length)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        string toReturn = string.Empty;
        while (length > 0)
        {
            toReturn += (char)rdn.Next(65, 90);
            length--;
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
```

I chose the range based on the ASCII table: https://www.asciitable.com/
If you also want a random `length` just create a new instance of `Random` in the calling method.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, here's a better way of doing it.

```cs
private static Random rdn = new Random();
private string RandomString(int length)
{
    return new string((char)rdn.Next('A', 'Z'), length);
}
```

Finally you can simply write: `replace1[index] = RandomString(4);`

Comment: Note that you might want to make your `Random` instance a private static; that way if this method is called many times in quick succession you don't get the same output.

Comment: Note that this is very inefficient if `length` is long.  The better bet is to create a char array of suitable length, or use a string builder.

Comment: Note that methods which modify their inputs are harder to debug. And your `length` variable no longer does what it says; it now means "characters remaining to add", not "length of string". Consider using a local `remaining` rather than modifying `length`.

Comment: Note that 65 and 90 are "magic numbers".  If you used `(int)'A'` instead of 65 the code gets more clear.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks, made an edit to improve my answer.

Comment: With your edit it now produces "AAAAAAA" or "zzzzzzzz", which is different than your original code.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Replace(string, string)` will replace every instance of the first parameter word with the second parameter word. If you want each individual instance of the same word to be replaced by a different string, you'll have to separate the string's word, iterate over them and everytime you find a word you want to replace, replace it with a random string.

Here's an example (assuming you already have a method to get a random word):

```
string Source = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\r\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string[] ReplaceWords = { "quick", "fox", "lazy", "dog" };

string[] SourceWords = Source.Split(' ');
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < SourceWords.Length; i++)
{
    if (ReplaceWords.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
        result += " " + GetRandomWord();
    else
        result += " " + SourceWords[i];
}
result = result.Trim() //Remove white spaces at the begining and end of the string.
```

`result = "The fdhs brown fdsfsd jumps over the hgfih turioutro.\r\nThe cxnvcxn brown oipuop jumps over the rewrre kmlçnlç."`

This way each instance of the words "quick", "fox", "lazy" and "dog" will be replaced by a different string. In my example, I obviously only stroke the keyboard randomly to illustrate my point, but if you have a `GetRandomWord` function that gets existing words from a list, it will work too:

`result = "The tree brown house jumps over the grass shell.\r\nThe hidrant brown mushroom jumps over the ocean skateboard."`

My examples are all retarded, but they illustrate my point.

I hope I helped :)

### Just for fun

If you make a `GetRandomWord` that selects words from existing lists AND it is context aware, you can get sentences that **might** actually make sense.

Let's create an `enum` for our contexts. For the sake of simplicity... Let's just keep it simple:

```
enum Context
{
    Adjective,
    Noun
}
```

Now let's create our lists:

```
string[] Nouns = {"dog", "cat", "fox", "horse", "bird"};
string[] Adjectives {"lazy", "sleepy", "quick", "big", "small"};
```

Now for our method:

```
string GetRandomWord(Context c)
{
    Random R = new Random();
    switch (c)
    {
        case Context.Noun:
            return Nouns[R.Next(0, Nouns.Length)];
            break;
        case Context.Adjective:
            return Adjectives[R.Next(0, Adjectives.Length)];
            break;
    }
}
```

Now a slight modification to the text replacing code:

```
string Source = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\r\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string[] ReplaceAdjectives = { "quick", "lazy" };
string[] ReplaceNouns = { "fox", "dog" };

string[] SourceWords = Source.Split(' ');
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < SourceWords.Length; i++)
{
    if (ReplaceAdjectives.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
        result += " " + GetRandomWord(Context.Adjective);
    else if (ReplaceNouns.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
        result += " " + GetRandomWord(Context.Noun);
    else
        result += " " + SourceWords[i];
}
result = result.Trim() //Remove white spaces at the begining and end of the string.
```

`result = "The sleepy brown bird jumps over the small horse.\r\nThe lazy brown cat jumps over the sleepy dog."`

Like I said, this way, the resulting random sentence MIGHT make some sense. But at least it will make some sense from the syntax point of view.

Because our lists match the indicies of the nouns with its corresponding sense-making adjectives, we can also modify the code so that we get random results that are guaranteed to make sense.

All we'd have to do is to create a new method called `GetMatchingWord(Context, int)`. It takes an int because it no longer randomizes the word selection by itself. This is now done in the calling method.

```
string GetMatchingWord(Context c, int i)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case Context.Noun:
            return Nouns[i];
            break;
        case Context.Adjective:
            return Adjectives[i];
            break;
    }
}
```

Then we modify our code accordingly:

```
string Source = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\r\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
string[] ReplaceAdjectives = { "quick", "lazy" };
string[] ReplaceNouns = { "fox", "dog" };

bool GuaranteeMatch = true;

string[] SourceWords = Source.Split(' ');
string result = "";
Random R = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < SourceWords.Length; i++)
{
    if (GuaranteeMatch)
    {
        int I = R.Next(0, Adjectives.Length) //Adjectives and Nouns have the same Length. This is a requirement for this method to work.
        if (ReplaceAdjectives.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
            result += " " + GetMatchingWord(Context.Adjective, I);
        else if (ReplaceNouns.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
            result += " " + GetMatchingWord(Context.Noun, I);
        else
            result += " " + SourceWords[i];
    }
    else
    {
        if (ReplaceAdjectives.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
            result += " " + GetRandomWord(Context.Adjective);
        else if (ReplaceNouns.Contains(SourceWords[i]))
            result += " " + GetRandomWord(Context.Noun);
        else
            result += " " + SourceWords[i];
    }
}
result = result.Trim() //Remove white spaces at the begining and end of the string.
```

Now, if `GuaranteeMatch` is true, we will always get results like:
`result = "The big brown horse jumps over the sleepy cat.\r\nThe lazy brown dog jumps over the small bird."`

It will even be possible for it to return the original sentence, since the words being replaced also exists in the lists of words to replace them with.